# How do I get my Google+ picture to show up on Google searches?

Tags: google, google-search, google-plus

I am looking to move my blog: [The Geek Tech Blog](http://thegeektechblog.blogspot.com) (which is currently a Blogger blog), over to a .com name with Wordpress. However, I still would lik my picture from Google+ to show up in search results like this, as it adds a personal touch to my blog:

[image: Google result for The Geek Tech Blog]

How do I make the picture show up on Google searches with a .com name and a Wordpress blog? I have no idea how that showed up in Google searches, as I did *nothing* to get the picture to show up (as far as I know).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to have a google+ account and [follow the instructions here for adding authorship information](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986).

> If you want your authorship information to appear in search results
>   for the content you create, you'll need a Google+ Profile with a good,
>   recognizable headshot as your profile photo. Then, verify authorship
>   of your content by associating it with your profile using either of
>   the methods below. Google doesn't guarantee to show author information
>   in Google Web Search or Google News results.

Matt Cutts recently tweeted [this interview with Google’s Sagar Kamdar](http://www.stonetemple.com/relauthor-defined-with-googles-sagar-kamdar/) concerning the rel=author microformat, it contains some clarity on how it works and implementation scenarios.

> Sagar Kamdar is a Group Product Manager for Google Search. Sagar is
>   responsible for Google’s authorship and social initiatives in search.
>   Prior to joining Google, Sagar was a Director responsible for
>   Analytics products at Oracle. Sagar has a BS degree in EE from Cornell
>   University.