# Using a company for Google authorship?

Tags: google-search, author, google-plus

Can you use a company's page as the author for google authorship or does it have to be an actual persons google + account for it to work ?

I.e. could i have it showing in search results as "-by acme co" rather than "-by simon smith "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2011/11/08/how-to-google-plus-brand-page/) has a good rundown on setting up a G+ brand page and you can find out how to implement authorship information in this answer to ["How do I get my Google+ picture to show up on Google searches?"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28379/how-do-i-get-my-google-picture-to-show-up-on-google-searches)

Answer (score 3):

Google+ pages can not be used as Authors. Authorship needs a profile (person). Company / Organisation can only have pages therefore they can only be publishers , not authors.

```
company/organisation page" rel="publisher" />
person profile" rel="author" />
```